# ngTagsInput in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using **tagsInput** Api in Angular

here is [link](http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/documentation/api)

i want to add a tag on space. but it is not working.

here is my code

```
<tags-input  ng-model="emails" placeholder="Add an Email"  [add-on-space="true"]>
```

Also i want to add Email **validator** in tags . i have no idea.

Any idea how to do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try dropping the square brackets from your attribute.  e.g.:

```
<tags-input  ng-model="emails" placeholder="Add an Email" add-on-space="true">
```

Square brackets are just used in their documentation to indicate the ones that are optional.  In its current form, your HTML isn't valid.

To validate emails, try the "allowed-tags-pattern" attribute with regex, as below:

```
<tags-input ng-model="emails" placeholder="Add an Email" add-on-space="true" allowed-tags-pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$">
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a solution for your emails (regex).  Give that a try.